# Cannot resolve symbol, but using-directive is right - build fails

Tags: c#, windows, dialog, messagedialog

```
using Windows.UI.Popups

{ ... uninteresting ...}

var _dialog = new MessageDialog("...","...");
```

Error:

> The type or namespace name "MessageDialog" could not be found

Comment: If it is such a stupid question that it´s worth giving a minus, why not provide a hint or - god beware - an answer instead

Comment: Compiler doesn't lie. Have you referenced appropriate metadata?